# JavaFX, variable does not update on actionEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue where I have a button and when clicked I want to update a value but I cannot update it because the lambda expression needs to be final. In this example I want to add to the current number the change number and save it, so there is a new current and every time I click the button, it takes it and add change. How can I get around this issue?

This is the class, I want when one of the buttons with an arrow is selected to either increase or decrease the value by 'int change'. Now, when you click the button it takes the current value and increases it by 'change' but it does not update it? How can I fix this?

And, also how can I add padding or margins to an imageView as I tried everything but it does not work? Or can I add padding to a specific part of a borderPane?

[Image with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8b3H.png)

```
private Pane getControls(String paneName, String imageName, String symbol, double min, double max, double def, double change) {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        ImageView image = getImage(imageName);
        image.setFitHeight(80);
        image.setFitWidth(60);

        Label defLabel;

        int current = (int) def;

        if (min > 20) {
            int def1 = (int) def;
            defLabel = new Label(def1 + "");
        } else {
            defLabel = new Label(def + "");
        }

        defLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #ff0000;");
        defLabel.setFont(new Font(50));

        Label symbolLabel = new Label(symbol);
        symbolLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #ffffff;");
        symbolLabel.setFont(new Font(24));

        symbolLabel.setPadding(new Insets(30, 40, 0, 0));

        borderPane.setRight(symbolLabel);
        borderPane.setCenter(defLabel);
        borderPane.setLeft(image);

        ImageView imageUp = getImage("up-icon.png");
        ImageView imageDown = getImage("down-icon.png");

        imageUp.setFitHeight(50);
        imageUp.setFitWidth(50);

        imageDown.setFitHeight(50);
        imageDown.setFitWidth(50);

        Button buttonUp = new Button();
        Button buttonDown = new Button();

        buttonUp.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            defLabel.setText((current + (int) change) + "");
            current += (int) change;
            System.out.println((current + (int) change) + " Up button pressed.");
        });
        buttonUp.setGraphic(imageUp);
        buttonDown.setGraphic(imageDown);

        buttonUp.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        buttonDown.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        buttonUp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6b4218;");
        buttonDown.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6b4218;");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(12);

        hbox.getChildren().add(buttonUp);
        hbox.getChildren().add(buttonDown);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 24, 0));

        borderPane.setBottom(hbox);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(100));

        BorderedTitledPane borderedTitledPane = new BorderedTitledPane(paneName, borderPane, 300, 200);
        return borderedTitledPane;
    }
```

Comment: you cannot change a varaible in a method scope from inside a labda. The method in which you created the labda will have already passed before your button is pressed.

Comment: if you provide more of the code for us, we could work out a solution

Comment: and please in textform, not as image

Comment: I added the code and more information, please tell if anything else can be added.

Comment: Just make it an instance variable (or wrap it in an object). Or use an `IntegerProperty` and bind the text of the label to it.

Comment: I fixed the issue by using AtomicInteger, it worked quite well. But I still cannot move the image a bit down and to the right, can you help with that?

Comment: oh if that's your code then you could have just moved 'int current = (int) def;' into your labda (right at the start of your lambda) and it would have worked. I thought you were trying to access 'current' somewhere after / outside your labda. But in your case just move the variable definition into the labda (def is also accessible within the labda, since you never set it's value twice outside the labda)

Comment: work through a tutorial on java language basics - your problem is not specific to javafx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I'll try to explain it to you using an example

If you don't understand my explaination, then read this tutorial (it is really well explained there): https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables

You can only access a variable from within a lambda if you could set that variable to final:

```
int i = 5; // You could set this variable to final and it would still compile
    
runSomething(() -> {
    System.out.println(i); // Will compile since i could be set final
});
```

and that's what happens when you change i again:

```
int i = 5; // i was defined
// ...
i = 10; // assigned new value to i therefore i could no longer be final

runSomething(() -> {
    System.out.println(i); // Will NOT compile since i could not be final anymore after it got changed
});
```

before Java 1.8+ we had to declare variables final to use them when implementing an interface (/ lambda (only exists since 1.8)) like this.

---

Therefore to access a variable from outside, (unless it is a field of a class) inside of a lamda you would need to be able to make it final. You can never change such a value (like you tried to) since you can't change final variables. Your 'current' variable is 'final' inside of your lambda, even though you never set it to final (this is because the method containing the variable could have already finished its execution before the lamda is being called from somewhere else. Since you can't alter the past the variable is unchangable inside the lamda body).

---

btw. your 'defLabel' is also 'final' inside of your lambda's body, since it never got changed (that's also why you can access it inside of the lamda)